# C# Razor Static Helper Error “Collection Was Modified”

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, helper

In my MVC web application I have a simple static Razor helper in  /App_Code/Functions.cshtml that I use to write out HTML for social media sharing on various different view pages:

```
@helper share (string url = null)
{
    if (url != null)
    {
        string fullUrl = "http://example.com" + url;

        <span class="share">
            <span class="text">Share</span>
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=@fullUrl " class="facebook">Facebook</a>
            <a href="https://www.twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=@fullUrl " class="twitter">Twitter</a>
            <a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=@fullUrl " class="google">Google+</a>
        </span>
    }
}
```

However, I sometimes get the error “Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute” especially when performing a site wide link check for example, and it always breaks on line 5 of the helper where it sets the “fullUrl” variable.

Since I’m not using any collections here, I don’t really know why this is happening or how to fix it. I suspect it could be something to do with thread safety but any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is an example stack trace from the error:

```
at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource resource)
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Enumerator.MoveNextRare()
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime.Tracing.BrowserLinkExecutionListener.GetOutputPositionTracker(TextWriter textWriter)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime.Tracing.BrowserLinkExecutionListener.BeginContext(PageExecutionContext context)
at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , Object )
at System.Web.WebPages.Instrumentation.PageExecutionListenerAdapter.BeginContext(PageExecutionContextAdapter context)
at System.Web.WebPages.Instrumentation.InstrumentationService.BeginContext(HttpContextBase context, String virtualPath, TextWriter writer, Int32 startPosition, Int32 length, Boolean isLiteral)
at System.Web.WebPages.HelperPage.BeginContext(TextWriter writer, String virtualPath, Int32 startPosition, Int32 length, Boolean isLiteral)
at ASP.Functions.<>c__DisplayClassc.<share>b__b(TextWriter __razor_helper_writer) in \App_Code\Functions.cshtml:line 143
at System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult.WriteTo(TextWriter writer)
at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageExecutingBase.WriteTo(TextWriter writer, HelperResult content)
at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.Write(HelperResult result)
at ASP._Page_Views_News__Article_cshtml.Execute() in \Views\_Article.cshtml:line 134
at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
at System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.RunPage()
at System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
at System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance)
at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)
at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
```

**UPDATE**

I've replicated the problem just doing the following...

Helper method in /App_Code/Functions.cshtml:

```
@helper Test ()
{
    @:test
}
```

Method call at the top of an empty view page:

```
@Functions.Test()
```

When the view is requested multiple times in succession as when performing a link check, every so often the same error occurs.

Comment: What is in line 143 of Functions.cshtml ?

Comment: `string fullUrl = "http://example.com" + url;` (it's line 5 of the helper but line 143 of Functions.cshtml)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code looks innocuous, so consider the stack trace. It might be to do with PageInspector. Here's [a possible fix](http://bchavez.bitarmory.com/archive/2012/12/28/rip-page-inspector-out-of-your-web-site-projects-now.aspx)

The core is to add this app setting in `web.config`;

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="PageInspector:ServerCodeMappingSupport" value="Disabled" />
</appSettings>
```

Or add this `<remove assembly=` tag in `web.config`;

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
  <assemblies>
    <remove assembly="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Loader, 
                      Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
                      PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

Comment: Hi Steve. Thank you so much for your answer, it seems to have solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting only occurs when you're modifying a list while iterating over it. For example:

```
foreach (var item in myList)
{
    myList.Remove(item);
}
```

Would raise this exception, because the length of the enumerable is being modified as it's being enumerated. The same would occur from an `Add`. You haven't posted any code like this, so the error is occuring outside of this code. Look for where you might be modifying a list within a `for` or `foreach` block, and that's where you're problem is.

Comment: Hi Chris. Yes, that makes perfect sense, only there aren't any `for` or `foreach` in my views! Is it not something to do with `__razor_helper_writer` and a collection associated with that?

Comment: It may not be actually in your view. It could be in the controller, or in some class the controller utilizes, an extension method or something that is called in the controller or in the view, etc. Somewhere, though, iteration is happening, and that's where your problem is.

Comment: The empty test view also used an empty controller so this is unlikely. It seems to have been an issue with Visual Studio and it's page inspector, as per the answer from Steve above. Running a link check on a published site build didn't give any errors, it only broke when running via VS on a local machine.